# Java 8 with Spring 3.1

Tags: spring, lambda, java-8

I have recently migrated one of my service using Spring 3.1 version from JDK 1.7 to JDK 8.

Are there any known issues with using JAVA 8 lambdas with Spring 3.1 version? My service uses spring heavily for all object autowiring as well as hibernate related annotations as well.

Comment: Test it but there is no guarantee it will work 100%. Versions 3.2 and before aren't really supported for java8 so you are basically on your own. I suggest upgrading to the latests 4.x version.

Comment: I did migration of big project from 3.2 to 4.x version and it was pretty smooth. Update Spring now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at [this blogpost](http://spring.io/blog/2013/05/21/spring-framework-4-0-m1-3-2-3-available/):

> Along with 4.0 M1, we’ve released Spring Framework 3.2.3, containing
>   fixes for recently reported issues but also coming with OpenJDK 8
>   runtime support. Spring Framework 3.2.x will support deployment on JDK
>   8 runtimes for applications compiled against JDK 7 (with -target 1.7)
>   or earlier. Note that it won’t support JDK 8’s bytecode format
>   (-target 1.8, as needed for lambdas); please upgrade to Spring
>   Framework 4.0 for that purpose.

So, Java 8 is supported as a runtime starting with Spring 3.2.x, but the code must be compiled against JDK 7. If you need/want to use Java 8 features, such as lambdas, etc. you will have to upgrade to Spring 4.